# .NET 7 SignalR not triggered in IIS but works on visual studio

Tags: c#, .net, chat, asp.net-core-signalr

I have a problem that my Signal R is not triggering in IIS. my SignalR is successfully connected and the SendMessage also work. but on **ReceiveMessage** is not working after deploy to IIS.

before this i get an error System.Data.Sqlclient.Tdsparser error connection, then i change it to await. after that the error not showing but the function not triggered

below is my code
chatHub.cs

```
private async void Dependency_OnChanged(object sender, TableDependency.SqlClient.Base.EventArgs.RecordChangedEventArgs<WfeVendorChats> e)
        {
            if (e.ChangeType != TableDependency.SqlClient.Base.Enums.ChangeType.None && e.Entity != null)
            {
                var changedEntity = e.Entity;

                // Filter the changes based on the table name
                if (changedEntity.GetType().Name == "WfeVendorChats")
                {
                    using (var connection = new SqlConnection(_configuration.GetConnectionString("ConnectionApp")))
                    {
                        await connection.OpenAsync();

                        var dbContextOptions = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<DataContext>()
                            .UseSqlServer(connection)
                            .EnableSensitiveDataLogging()
                            .Options;

                        using (var dbContext = new DataContext(dbContextOptions, _user, _detection, _httpContextAccessor))
                        {
                            
                            //my code for chatvm
                            await _hubContext.Clients.All.SendAsync("ReceiveMessage", chatvm.OrderByDescending(o => o.createdDate).ToList());
                        }

                        connection.Close();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

my js code

```
//SignalR connection
Object.defineProperty(WebSocket, 'OPEN', { value: 1, });
var connection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder().withUrl("/chatHub").build();
async function start() {
    try {
        await connection.start();
        console.log("SignalR connected successfully.");
    } catch (err) {
        console.error("SignalR connection error: " + err);
    }
}
connection.on("ReceiveMessage", (message) => {
    var leftpanel = $('ul.list-group.elements-list');
    leftpanel.empty();
    var chatpanel = $('.tab-content');
    chatpanel.empty();
    // Handle received message
    console.log('ReceiveMessage');
    displayMessage(message);
});

start().then(() => {
    // Connection started
    //connection.invoke("JoinOrderRoom", orderNumber);
    console.log('signal R connected #IFL');

    // Retrieve chat history for the order number
    var Productid = $('#linkedProductId').val();
    retrieveChatHistory(Productid);

    //If chat open from linked product
    var linkprdId = $('#linkedProductId').val();
    var linkprdName = $('#linkedProductName').val();

    console.log(linkprdId);

    if (linkprdId != '' && linkprdId != undefined) {
        console.log('masuk');
        $('#divAtt').show();
        $(".attachment-box").show();
        $("#chatAtt").attr('href', '/Layanan/' + $('#linkedProductId').val() + '/DetailProduct');
        $("#nameAtt").text('Product : ' + linkprdId + ' - ' + linkprdName);
    }

    $("#sendButton").click(() => {
        var message = $('#txtChatBoxNewMessage').val();
        var vendorId = $(".tab-right-panel.active .vendor_id").val();
        var productId = $(".tab-right-panel.active .product_id").val();
        var orderNumber = $(".tab-right-panel.active .order_number").val();
        var partnerId = $(".tab-right-panel.active .partner_id").val();
        var linkUrl = $('#chatAtt').attr('href');
        var Filename = $('#nameAtt').text();
        connection.invoke("SendMessage", message, vendorId, productId, orderNumber, partnerId, linkUrl, Filename);
        $('.attachment-box a.pull-right').click();
        $('#txtChatBoxNewMessage').val('');
    });
}).catch((err) => {
    console.log(err);
    console.error(err.toString());
});
```

this function is working perfectly in Visual Studio but not working in IIS. a already installed .net 7 and WebSocket in server, but its not working in **ReceiveMessage**. any help will be gratefull, thanks

Comment: What is the status code that is getting returned?  IIS is very old and the authentication method may not work especially if the certificate is a TLS 1.3 certificate.

Comment: @jdweng there is no status code, the ReceiveMessage does not triggered in IIS. but it works on vs iis express

Comment: There should be a status code if the connection completed.  If you do not get a status code then it indicates the connection failed to complete.  When a connection doesn't complete there is a timeout that occurs that triggers an exception.  You failure could happen for lots of reasons.  Since code is working and only failing on IIS is probably has to do with encryption on IIS not supporting the newer encryption algorithms.  The following may help troubleshoot you issue : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/troubleshoot?view=aspnetcore-7.0

Comment: You application has a front end which is a http connection between a client and server; and you application has a backend which is a connection between the server and the database.   One reason for failure is the credentials on the front end are not being passed (or rejected) on the backend connection.  Check the connection string used to access the database.

Comment: @jdweng before this i get error System.Data.Sqlclient.Tdsparser error connection, then i change it to await. the error not showing but the function not triggered

Comment: Please check the official doc and enable the server-side and client-side logging, then share with us. Here is the link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/diagnostics?view=aspnetcore-7.0

Comment: By the way, pls find the project_name.exe inside the bin folder and double-click it, check the issue could be reproduced or not ?

Comment: I do not know anything about the database.  Is database on same machine when code worked and did not work?  I would check the log files in database with SQL Server Management Studio.  The log file can be found in the SSMS explorer under Management.  I would check for errors during connection an verify the group/user that was used to login.  Compare against the group/user when code worked.